# I need to start my page with a plain background and then let it change based on the video the user selects

Tags: function, video, background, addeventlistener

My page consists of three different videos.
I want to have the page start with a plain background and based on what the user selects, have that video as the background.
I don't know how to make the function correctly for a plain background to change to the video the user selects.

I tried to create a function that selects the class that contains the background color and have it change using  addEventListener ('click', function()).

My code is incorrect because when it runs, nothing works except the timer.

`

````
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Personal Prayer App</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Acme&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="app">
        <div class="vid-container">
            <video loop>
                <source src="./Vids/rainHDbyJeanVanDerMeulenonPixabay.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>



        <div class="time-select">
            <button data-time="900">15 minutes</button>
            <button data-time="2100">35 minutes</button>
            <button data-time="3600">60 minutes</button>
        </div>

        <div class="player-container">
            <audio class ="song">
                <source src="Sounds/light-rain-ambient-114354.mp3">
            </audio>
            <img src="Pics/play-button-svgrepo-com.svg" alt="playbutton" class="play">

            <svg 
            class="track-outline"
            width="453" 
            height="453" 
            viewBox="0 0 453 453" 
            fill="none" 
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            >
            <circle 
            cx="226.5" 
            cy="226.5" 
            r="216.5" 
            stroke="white" 
            stroke-width="20"
            />
            </svg>
            <svg 
            class="moving-outline"
            width="453" 
            height="453" 
            viewBox="0 0 453 453" 
            fill="none" 
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            >
            <circle 
            cx="226.5" 
            cy="226.5" 
            r="216.5" 
            stroke="blue" 
            stroke-width="20"
            />
            </svg>
            <h3 class="time-display">0:00</h3>
        </div>


        <div class="sound-picker">
            <button data-sound="./Sounds/light-rain-ambient-114354.mp3" 
     data-video="./Vids/HDRainbyrelaxing-guru-4757483-1920x1080-30fps.mp4">
                <img src="./Pics/Rain-inge-maria-unsplash.jpg" alt="rain">
            </button>
            <button data-sound="./Sounds/forest-river-birds-recording-6735.mp3" 
    data-video="./Vids/robinbyFedericoMadernoOnPixabay-21723.mp4">
                <img src="./Pics/ForestRiver-paul-siewert-unsplash.jpg" alt="Forest and River">
            </button>
            <button data-sound="./Sounds/mixkit-sea-coast-breaking-waves-1206.wav" 
    data-video="./Vids/seaHD-javier-lemus-2439510-1920x1080-30fps.mp4">
                <img src="./Pics/oceanbyivan-bandura-unsplash.jpg" alt="waves">
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    


    <script src="script.js">
    // QUESTIONS:  
    //const background = document.querySelector('.app')
    // background.forEach(option => {
    //     option.addEventListener('click', function(){
    //         video.src=this.getAttribute('data-video');
    //     })
    // })
    ///How can I change the background from a color to the video?///

    const app = () => {
    const song = document.querySelector('.song');
    const play = document.querySelector('.play');
    const outline = document.querySelector('.moving-outline circle');
    
    //question remains, how do I make a player circle? where do you get this from? 
  //how can you make it from scratch?//

    const video = document.querySelector('.vid-container video');
    const sounds = document.querySelectorAll('.sound-picker button');
    const timeDisplay = document.querySelector('.time-display');
    //get the length of outline
    const outlineLength = outline.getTotalLength();
    console.log(outlineLength)
    //Duration
    const timeSelect = document.querySelectorAll('.time-select button');
    
    
    
    let fakeDuration = 600
    outline.style.strokeDasharray = outlineLength;
    outline.style.strokeDashoffset = outlineLength;
    
    //pick different sounds
    sounds.forEach(option => {
        option.addEventListener('click', function () {
            song.src = this.getAttribute('data-sound');
            video.src = this.getAttribute('data-video');
            checkPlaying(song);
        })
        
    })
    
    
    
    //play sound
    play.addEventListener('click', () => {
        checkPlaying(song);
        
    })


    timeSelect.forEach(option => {
    option.addEventListener('click', function () {
        fakeDuration = this.getAttribute('data-time');
    timeDisplay.textContent = `${Math.floor(fakeDuration / 60)} : 
    ${Math.floor(fakeDuration %    60)}`
    })
    })

    //lets make a function to stop and play sounds
    const checkPlaying = song => {
    if (song.paused) {
        song.play();
        video.play()
        play.src = "./Pics/video-pause-button-svgrepo-com.svg";
    } else {
        song.pause();
        video.pause();
        play.src = "./Pics/play-button-svgrepo-com.svg";
    }
    }

    //now let's animate the circle
    song.ontimeupdate = () => {
    let currentTime = song.currentTime;
    let elapsed = fakeDuration - currentTime;
    let seconds = Math.floor(elapsed % 60);
    let minutes = Math.floor(elapsed / 60);
    
    //animate the bar
    let progress = outlineLength - (currentTime / fakeDuration) * outlineLength
    outline.style.strokeDashoffset = progress;
    
    //time display
    timeDisplay.textContent = `${minutes}:${seconds}`
    
    if (currentTime >= fakeDuration) {
        song.currentTime = 0;
        song.pause();
        play.src = "./Pics/play-button-svgrepo-com.svg";
        video.pause();
    }
    }
    }

   app();

    </script>
    </body>

    </html>`
    ```

    * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .app {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
   /* background: pink;
    /*how can I have a background color but then change
    it based on a selection?*/
    }

    .time-select,
    .sound-picker,
    .player-container {
    height: 80%;
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    }

    img.play{
    height:25%;
    background-color: lightblue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    }

    .player-container {
    position: relative;
    }

.player-container svg {
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)rotate(-90deg)
}

    svg.moving-outline{
    background-color: ;
    
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: .9;
    }

   
    /*.time-select {
    background: lightblue;
    }

    .sound-picker {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    }*/

    .sound-picker img {
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 4px solid black;
    }

    /*.player-container {
    background-color: rosybrown;

    }*/

    .time-display {
    position: absolute;
    color: black;
    bottom: 10%;
    color:black;
    font-size: 88px;
    background-color: rgb(223, 234, 22);
    opacity: .1;
    font-family: 'Acme', sans-serif;
    opacity: .2;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding:20px;
    animation: time-display 5s ease infinite;
    }
    @keyframes time-display {
    0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(.3);
   }
   50% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.05);
   }
   70% { transform: scale(.9); }
   100% { transform: scale(1); }
   }



    video {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    z-index: -10;
    }

    .time-select button,
    .sound-picker button {
    color: black;
    width: 30%;
    height: 10%;
    border: 2px solid white;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;

    }

    .time-select button{
    height: 20%;
    width: 40%;
    border-radius: 45%;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 200%;
    opacity:.8;
    border-color: 10px solid lightblue;
    font-family:'Acme', sans-serif;
    }

    .time-select button:hover {
    color: black;
    background: white;
    font-size: 50px;
    opacity: .5;
    /*add cool hover effect*/
    }

    .sound-picker button {
    border: none;
    height: 420px;
    width: 420px;
    margin:10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 4px solid gainsboro;
    transition: .2s;
    }

    .sound-picker :hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    
    }

    .sound-picker button:nth-child(1) {
    background: rgb(48, 136, 136);
    }

    .sound-picker button:nth-child(2) {
    background: rgb(231, 112, 69);
    }

    .sound-picker button:nth-child(3) {
    background: rgb(205, 251, 113);
    }
````

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).